# TVirtualStringTree - how to set alignment of text in cell on per-row basis?

Tags: delphi, virtualtreeview

I need to set the alignment (justification) of text in a particular column differently depending on the particular row.

To set the alignment of the entire column I know that there's a Header.Columns[col].Alignment property.

For cells in specific rows I am assuming that needs to be handled "virtually", by setting something in one of the events that occurs during the drawing sequence.

Of is it necessary to custom-implement the actual drawing of the text, for example in OnDrawText?  Thanks.